# Check property changes without timer (C#)

Tags: c#, events, properties, timer

Let's say,

- I have an instance of FileInfo,
- I want my program to check for file changes and
- the FileInfo class doesn't provide events for that task.

Is there a better way than using a timer to check the FileInfo's properties and throw an event, if those properties changed?

I want to check a file for changes without opening it.

Comment: If it's just to detect changes, maybe you can use a `FileSystemWatcher`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FileSystemWatcher.Changed event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.changed%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is what you are looking for.